# c++ for-loop end condition doesn't work when size() is used

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
vector<int> score= {1,1,1,1,1};
    int z = score.size();
    for(int j=score.size() - 1; j >= z - 5; --j)
        cout << j << endl;
```

The code right now is fine but causes an error when I replace that line with:

`for(int j=score.size() - 1; j >= score.size() - 5; --j)`

From the print out, I've deducted it's because j goes to -1 and beyond. My question is why is this happening when I just substituted z for the size() function? The inside of the for loop does not modify size[i].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression:

```
j >= z - 5
```

since both `j` and `z` are `int` the comparison works fine since the left hand side can be `-1` when `j` becomes `-1`.

In this expression:

```
j >= score.size() - 5
```

the right hand side is `unsigned`, so the left hand side is implicitly converted to `unsigned` as well. When `j` becomes `-1` that conversion gives a very large integer, and the comparison doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Strictly speaking, conversion to the common type is not a *promotion*. It's just a(n implicit) conversion.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, that's a good point. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`size()` is *unsigned*, so `size()-1` and `size()-5` will also be unsigned (though you are assigning the 1st value to a *signed* `int`). `j >= score.size() - 5` is comparing a *signed* integer `j` to an *unsigned* integer `size()-5`.